# How can I delete unavailable URL in browser history using C# .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, browser-history

I'm building an animal feed supplying website using C# .NET

It has those features below:
http://localhost:52000/Account/Index  =>show a list of accounts (ID, name...).

Click on an ID from **Index page**, it leads into **Detail page**: http://localhost:52000/Account/Details/6cc608a5-3b4b-4c6f-b220-3422c984919a

In account detail's page, it also has 2 buttons(functions): **Delete** account and **Edit** account information.

All I want is after deleting an account (in Detail view), website will redirect to the previous available page (Index,...). Therefore I use `window.location.href = "/Account/Index/";` in Delete function.

Here is my delete function with redirecting solution:

```
function deleteAccount(id) {
            var data = { 'id': id };
            $.ajax({
                *//....*

                success: function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                         *//redirect to the previous page (Index)*
                         window.location.href = "/Account/Index/";
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

However,after deleting and redirecting to `"/Account/Index/"` successfully, if Admin click on **Back** Button on Browser, website redirect to unavailable page (the Detail page of that deleted account: http://localhost:52000/Account/Detail/6cc608a5-3b4b-4c6f-b220-3422c984919a).

Then I tried to use `window.history.back();`, `window.history.go(-1);`, `window.location.replace("/Account/Index/");` in turn instead, it worked perfectly only when Admin just deletes that account, if Admin Edits this account first then updates then deletes `(Press Edit in Detail view -> Go to Edit view -> press Update -> Go back to Detail View )` --> website redirect to unavailable page (the editing page of that deleted account: http://localhost:52000/Account/Edit/6cc608a5-3b4b-4c6f-b220-3422c984919a).

```
function deleteAccount(id) {
            var data = { 'id': id };
            $.ajax({
                *//....*

                success: function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                         *//redirect to the previous page (Index)*
                         window.history.back(); 
                         // or window.history.go(-1)
                         //or window.location.replace("/Account/Index/");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Is that possible to remove the unavailable URLs (those include ID of deleted account) in browser? How can I handle the Back Button in Browser to go through those unavailable URLs? (http://localhost:52000/Account/Detail/6cc608a5-3b4b-4c6f-b220-3422c984919a and http://localhost:52000/Account/Edit/6cc608a5-3b4b-4c6f-b220-3422c984919a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with the following:

```
window.location.replace("/Account/Index/");
```

This is the equivalent of an HTTP redirect using Javascript.

When you use `window.location.href` it would be as if a user has clicked on a link and therefore you can go back to the previous URL afterwards.

Comment: Hi, it should work. Make sure you are not assigning instead of calling the method i.e. It is not window.location.replace = "/Account/Index/" but window.location.replace("/Account/Index/");

Comment: It doesn't work with this situation: view account Detail -> press Edit -> Press Update ( return RedirectToAction("Details", "Account", new { id = accountID});) -> back to view Detail Page -> press Delete. After deleting, it redirect to Index successfully but If I click on Back button on Browser, it again redirect to http://localhost:52077/Account/Edit/80800dce-811b-4009-a270-301b5d86776b

Comment: That is the expected behaviour because you did some server side redirects too. The javascript bit is only preventing you to go back to the details page, but you still have your edit page in your browser history.

Comment: You may want to look into reactjs or angular for a better solution.